# camera_calibration runs but cannot calibrate

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I tried to calibrate my Firefly MV Firewire camera with the provided ROS Indigo package.
So I ran roscore and camera1394, and then the command on the wiki.

The wiki says that to start the calibration I have to press the Calibrate Button but it is gray and nothing happens when I press it.

Anyone can help me?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

This is the command I ran:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x5 --square 0.030 image:=/camera/image_raw camera:=/camera
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206988/camera_calibration-runs-but-cannot-calibrate/) by [mark_vision](https://answers.ros.org/users/11321/mark_vision/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to collect the samples first, then the the 'calibrate' button will be enabled

---

Originally posted by [clynamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8871/clynamen/) with karma: 61 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0